# Django: Difference between cached session vs simple cache?

Tags: django, session, caching

I have a Django application using Redis as a cached session backend (not persistent). If I am say storing only one value in a user's session, is there any storage difference between say -

```
request.session['value'] = value
```

and

```
cache.set(user_identifier, value)
```

apart from timeout/logout? Is there any con in using only cache with keys related to user_identifier vs storing values in user's session?

Comment: In terms of storage there's no difference imo. The advantage of using the `session` is that it's tightly coupled to the user. You get all the goodies from Django that saves new session variables automatically for each request, commands to remove stale sessions and encryption of the session data (which you'd have to do manually if you just set cache variables). So I'd say less work to keep user-sensitive data secure.

Comment: @dirkgroten Encryption is a good point. The only problem I find with sessions is if I want to change some variables for select users, not straightforward. Guess I'll use cache for insensitive data. Thanks!

Comment: There is a simple way to connect users to their sessions (for logged in users, not anonymous users obviously) described [here](http://gavinballard.com/associating-django-users-sessions/). That way you can also get session data for a user that's not making the current request or outside of the request flow (in models for example).